# Can I set a delay on startup sounds?

Tags: startup, shutdown

Is there a way to have the start up sound wait like I did in conky like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
```

Not that its a big deal but my comp boots so fast it does not have time to play the small ogg file i have as the start up sound. 
Or any other ideas on what i can do to get it to play?? Also shutdown goes so fast it does not finish that sound either? 
And as allways TYAVMIA :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutdown sounds were removed from Gnome, unfortunately. As for startup sounds, they should play fine (you shouldn't need to delay them; they'll continue to play after your desktop is available).

In *System / Preferences / Startup Applications* verify that "GNOME Login Sound" is enabled:
[image]

To configure a custom start-up sound, you'll have to create it manually at the moment:

```
mkdir - ~/.local/share/sounds/mysound
cd ~/.local/share/sounds/mysound
ln -s /the/sound/file/you/want.ogg desktop-login.ogg
```

And then in the same directory, create the file `index.theme`:

```
[Sound Theme]
Name=MySound
Inherits=ubuntu
Directories=.
```

Then you'll be able to select your theme in the drop-down of *System / Preferences / Sound / Sound Effects / Sound theme*.